# Blockly customized app crashes

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, developer-tools, blockly

I am working on Google Blockly for Android. I have created my custom blocks using Blockly developer tools and I have added it to my assets folder and have referenced it in my app code too, following is my Main method code:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.evgenii.jsevaluator.JsEvaluator;
import com.evgenii.jsevaluator.interfaces.JsCallback;
import com.google.blockly.android.AbstractBlocklyActivity;
import com.google.blockly.android.codegen.CodeGenerationRequest;
import com.google.blockly.android.codegen.LoggingCodeGeneratorCallback;
import com.google.blockly.model.DefaultBlocks;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AbstractBlocklyActivity {

JsEvaluator jsEvaluator = new JsEvaluator(this);

private static final String TAG = "SimpleActivity";

private static final String SAVE_FILENAME = "simple_workspace.xml";
private static final String AUTOSAVE_FILENAME = "simple_workspace_temp.xml";

public static final String TOOLBOX_PATH = "roboapp_toolbox1.xml";

// Add custom blocks to this list.
private static final List<String> BLOCK_DEFINITIONS = Arrays.asList(
        "blocks/block_definitions.json"
);
private static final List<String> JAVASCRIPT_GENERATORS = Arrays.asList(
        // Custom block generators go here. Default blocks are already 
included.
        "blocks/code_generator.js"
);
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private final CodeGenerationRequest.CodeGeneratorCallback 
mCodeGeneratorCallback =
        new CodeGenerationRequest.CodeGeneratorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinishCodeGeneration(final String generatedCode) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
generatedCode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        jsEvaluator.evaluate(generatedCode, new JsCallback() 
{
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(String result) {
                                // Process result here.
                                // This method is called in the UI thread.

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(String errorMessage) {
                                // Process JavaScript error here.
                                // This method is called in the UI thread.
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        };


/*CodeGenerationRequest.CodeGeneratorCallback mCodeGeneratorCallback =
        new LoggingCodeGeneratorCallback(this, TAG);*/

@NonNull
@Override
protected List<String> getBlockDefinitionsJsonPaths() {
    return BLOCK_DEFINITIONS;
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected String getToolboxContentsXmlPath() {
    // Replace with a toolbox that includes application specific blocks.
    return TOOLBOX_PATH;
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected List<String> getGeneratorsJsPaths() {
    return JAVASCRIPT_GENERATORS;
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected CodeGenerationRequest.CodeGeneratorCallback getCodeGenerationCallback() {
    // Uses the same callback for every generation call.
    return mCodeGeneratorCallback;
}

/**
 * Optional override of the save path, since this demo Activity has multiple Blockly
 * configurations.
 * @return Workspace save path used by SimpleActivity and SimpleFragment.
 */
@Override
@NonNull
protected String getWorkspaceSavePath() {
    return SAVE_FILENAME;
}

/**
 * Optional override of the auto-save path, since this demo Activity has multiple Blockly
 * configurations.
 * @return Workspace auto-save path used by SimpleActivity and SimpleFragment.
 */
@Override
@NonNull
protected String getWorkspaceAutosavePath() {
    return AUTOSAVE_FILENAME;
}
}
```

All the block definitions,code generator and toolbox files are in their respective places as mentioned in the code.

**Now my problem is that upon running the app,the apk is installed but the app stops working. ** . It shows the following error in the run:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String 
android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String) (tried 
Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and 
 Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2)
at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method)
at android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:52)
at android.os.Environment.getCanonicalPathOrNull(Environment.java:832)
at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:83)
at android.os.Environment.
getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:419)
at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:101)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
Aborted
```

and Logcat shows the following error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: app.robo.com.roboapp, PID: 13104
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.robo.com.roboapp/app.robo.com.roboapp.MainActivity}:
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load toolbox XML.
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load toolbox XML.
      at com.google.blockly.android.BlocklyActivityHelper.reloadToolbox(BlocklyActivityHelper.java:670)
      at com.google.blockly.android.AbstractBlocklyActivity.reloadToolbox(AbstractBlocklyActivity.java:649)
      at com.google.blockly.android.AbstractBlocklyActivity.onCreate(AbstractBlocklyActivity.java:256)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: blocks/roboapp_toolbox1.xml
      at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
      at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:318)
      at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:292)
      at com.google.blockly.android.BlocklyActivityHelper.reloadToolbox(BlocklyActivityHelper.java:667)
      at com.google.blockly.android.AbstractBlocklyActivity.reloadToolbox(AbstractBlocklyActivity.java:649) 
      at com.google.blockly.android.AbstractBlocklyActivity.onCreate(AbstractBlocklyActivity.java:256) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

My toolbox xml is generated by the Blockly Developer tools and is as follows:

```
<toolbox>
<category name="Movements" colour="#5ba5a5">
<block type="movement_robot">
  <field name="time">1</field>
  <field name="angle">90</field>
  <field name="NAME">slow</field>
</block>
<block type="movement_stop"></block>
<block type="movement_speed">
  <field name="setspeed">sspeed</field>
  <field name="NAME">90</field>
</block>
</category>
<category name="Controls" colour="#a56d5b">
<block type="control_for_do">
  <field name="time">0</field>
</block>
<block type="control_wait">
  <field name="time">0</field>
</block>
<block type="control_exit"></block>
</category>
<category name="Loops" colour="#6da55b">
<block type="controls_repeat_ext">
  <value name="TIMES">
    <shadow type="math_number">
      <field name="NUM">10</field>
    </shadow>
  </value>
</block>
<block type="controls_whileUntil">
  <field name="MODE">WHILE</field>
</block>
</category>
<category name="Appearance" colour="#5b6da5">
<block type="app_headlights">
  <value name="NAME">
    <block type="logic_boolean">
      <field name="BOOL">FALSE</field>
    </block>
  </value>
</block>
<block type="app_backlight">
  <value name="NAME">
    <block type="logic_boolean">
      <field name="BOOL">FALSE</field>
    </block>
  </value>
</block>
</category>
</toolbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileNotFoundException: blocks/roboapp_toolbox1.xml`

Make sure your toolbox XML is located at `assets/blocks/roboapp_toolbox1.xml`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I sorted it out, the problem was that some of the blocks were custom created and some of them were given already so I needed to state the xmlPaths and codeGenerators for all of them, here I gave the paths for only the blocks that I created. So I added the path for all of them and it worked !